# Distance from point stored in geometry with SRID 4326

Tags: postgis, distance, srid, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I have stored 2.5 million data points (addresses) using the geometry data type in column latlong with SRID 4326. The latlon - column has a GIST index defined. I would select all addresses within a distance given in metres.

I understand that SRID 4326 measures distance in degrees, so it doesn't make sense in my case. However the query

```
select *
from adresse
where st_distance(latlong::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(16.520, 47.846), 4326)::geography) < 200
```

is incredibly slow, I guess it is unable to use the index.

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Have you tried to sava data as geography instead of using cast?

Comment: Did that and it already helped a lot. Casting prevents using the index, at least it seems to be in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [ST_DWithin()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) which takes advantage of indexing

```
SELECT *
FROM adresse
WHERE ST_DWithin(latlong::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(16.520, 47.846), 4326)::geography, 200)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(latlong::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(16.520, 47.846), 4326)::geography);
```

See also http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/

Comment: ST_DWithin was already at least 10 times faster. After adding an additional column of type geography, defining and index and using ST_DWithin I am now in the area of milliseconds. Mission accomplished.